# Mysql value as label matrix

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have following data in table given in sql fiddle.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6d8fd5/1

**Problem** : In following output it repeat same value in all column.

```
label           XS        S       M       L      XL      2XL     3XL     4XL
Chest girth     70       70      70      70      70      70      70      70
length          66       66      66      66      66      66      66      66
Sleeve length   62       62      62      62      62      62      62      62
```

**Solution**: I want **XS** value in **XS** column, **S** value in **S** column etc.

My SQL Query:

```
SELECT
  label,
  VALUE AS XS,
  VALUE AS S,
  VALUE AS M,
  VALUE AS L,
  VALUE AS XL,
  VALUE AS 2XL,
  VALUE AS 3XL,
  VALUE AS 4XL  
FROM
  test
GROUP BY
   label
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Query like this to get your result:

```
SELECT
  label,
  MAX(IF(size_label = 'XS', VALUE,null)) AS XS,
  MAX(IF(size_label = 'S ', VALUE,null)) AS S,
  MAX(IF(size_label = 'M',  VALUE,null)) AS M,
  MAX(IF(size_label = 'L',  VALUE,null)) AS L,
  MAX(IF(size_label = 'XL', VALUE,null)) AS XL,
  MAX(IF(size_label = '2XL',VALUE,null)) AS 2XL,
  MAX(IF(size_label = '3XL',VALUE,null)) AS 3XL,
  MAX(IF(size_label = '4XL',VALUE,null)) AS 4XL
FROM
  test
GROUP BY
   label;
```

**sample**

```
MariaDB [yourschema]> SELECT
    ->   label,
    ->   MAX(IF(size_label = 'XS', VALUE,null)) AS XS,
    ->   MAX(IF(size_label = 'S ', VALUE,null)) AS S,
    ->   MAX(IF(size_label = 'M',  VALUE,null)) AS M,
    ->   MAX(IF(size_label = 'L',  VALUE,null)) AS L,
    ->   MAX(IF(size_label = 'XL', VALUE,null)) AS XL,
    ->   MAX(IF(size_label = '2XL',VALUE,null)) AS 2XL,
    ->   MAX(IF(size_label = '3XL',VALUE,null)) AS 3XL,
    ->   MAX(IF(size_label = '4XL',VALUE,null)) AS 4XL
    -> FROM
    ->   test
    -> GROUP BY
    ->    label;
+---------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| label         | XS   | S    | M    | L    | XL   | 2XL  | 3XL  | 4XL  |
+---------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| Chest girth   |   70 |   71 |   72 |   73 |   74 |   75 |   76 |   77 |
| length        |   66 |   67 |   68 |   69 |   70 |   71 |   72 |   73 |
| Sleeve length |   62 |   63 |   64 |   65 |   66 |   67 |   68 |   69 |
+---------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [yourschema]>
```